# syntax error in FROM clause in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim nm As String
Dim pass As String
nm = TextBox1.Text
pass = TextBox2.Text

Try
    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Pavilion\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication5\Ent.accdb"
    cn.Open()
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE UName='" & nm & "'AND Pwd='" & pass & "'"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, cn)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While (dr.Read())
        If ((nm.Equals(dr(0))) And pass.Equals(dr(1))) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Login Sucessful")
        End If
    End While
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Login Failed :" & ex.Message)
End Try
```

This code is giving the following error `syntax error in FROM clause`

Answer (score 2):

@Tim is correct, but I think you might also have problem with your SQL as `user` is a reserved word. If I execute

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE UName='fred' AND Pwd='123'
```

in SQL Server

I get told `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.`

You can overcome this by putting [] around the tablename, i.e.

```
Select * FROM [user] WHERE UName='fred' AND Pwd='123'
```

Comment: Good point - though as OP is using OleDb it might not be SQL Server.  Using `[]` shouldn't hurt anything however; better safe than sorry.

Comment: The connection string suggests Access, and User is a keyword there too.

Answer (score 1):

If the code you posted is copy and paste, you're missing a space between the username and the AND keyword.

Your code:

```
"SELECT * FROM user WHERE UName='" & nm & "'AND Pwd='" & pass & "'"
```

Should be:

```
"SELECT * FROM user WHERE UName='" & nm & "' AND Pwd='" & pass & "'"
```

However, you should use parameterized queries to avoid the possibility of SQL injection attacks.  Something like this:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE UName=@nm AND Pwd=@pass"
cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, cn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nm", TextBox1.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", TextBox2.Text)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try

            cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Pavilion\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication5\Ent.accdb"
            cn.Open()
            Dim sql As String
            sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE UName='" + nm + "'AND Pwd='" + pass + "'"
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, cn)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            While (dr.Read())
                If ((nm.Equals(dr(0))) And pass.Equals(dr(1))) Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Login Sucessful")
                End If
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Login Failed :" & ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Comment: How is this code different from the OP's posted code?  Except for moving the beginning of the try block, I can't see any differences...

Comment: Your edit **still** doesn't answer the question - it's the **exact same code** that OP posted in the question!  If you're going to answer a question, then answer it - and posting an explanation *along* with code is almost always helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
 "SELECT Firstname FROM [RegUser] where Firstname=@d3 and password=@d4"
```

i just enclose my table name into brackets and its done.. it works actually
i hope this will help you a lot..

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution. Please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59628706/edit) to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead